# Зачем использовать getElementById, если можно получить элемент через переменную с именем, равным значению атрибута id?

Tags: javascript

Собственно век живи век учись!

```js
window.onload = function() {
  div_1.onclick = function() {
    div_2.value = div_1.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div_1">TEXT</div>
<input type="text" id="div_2" value="" />
```

Работает во всех браузерах которые есть только на компе!

Вопрос: Зачем объявлять переменную типа как

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
```

и потом к ней обращаться, если обращение можно сделать сразу к **`mydiv`**? Поясните!

**UPD:** @ling жду Ваш персональный визит! Ваши знания были испытаны собственным js кодом не раз)

Comment: О_о думаю камни подводные тут есть

Comment: Т.е. по Вашему 4 строчки короче, чем одна? Или я не понял?

Comment: @butteff, он про обращение:

    div_2.value

Comment: Собственно жду **гуру**)

Comment: Поддерживаю ответ Alex'а. Еще может быть, чтобы переменные не мешать. Объявили вы допустим где-нибудь переменную window.mydiv как string. А потом захотели обратиться к Dom'у с таким же ID, а вам js дулю (ну или еще че) покажет)) А вообще Вам @Palmervan большое спасибо) Только щас узнал, что так можно делать)

Comment: @Dobby007 та я сам был вшоке)

Comment: @Alex Silaev возражений не имею, все принято к сведению! Ответ принят!

Comment: @Palmervan, Вы почаще отставайте от жизни =) С рождения ничего подобного не знал и даже в голову не приходило) + к вопросу))

Comment: Я недавно вот что для себя открыл

    var obj = {};
    var n = function() { return false; }
    var obj2 = { a: 15 }
    obj[n] = 3;
    obj[obj2] = 5;

По-моему, это страшно))

Comment: Ага, действительно страшно!!!  
Думаю, читать такое в чужом коде - ...... просто нет слов)

Comment: Проверил. При добавлении doctype'а код не работает в FF. Плюс, как уже было сказано, не факт, что этот стиль кода сохранится в следующих версиях браузеров.

Comment: @ling вам бы тоже почитать мой ответ по этому поводу

Comment: Почитал, плюсанул. Почитал также и Yura Ivanov. Такое ощущение, что рано или поздно либо сделают полновесную поддержку такого именования, либо его выпилят из стандартов. Мне лично это не нравится, как раз по причине захламления кода.

Comment: @Sh4dow, ну, я думаю, открытие в универсальности названия свойства (в смысле переменная какого типа будет в его названии).
В первом случае свойство назвалось логической переменной false, то есть можно было обратиться к нему и как к false, просто функция вернула false.
Во втором случае, свойство "назвали" объектом. Мдо, круто)

Comment: @Sh4dow - никто не заставляет писать такой бред, но то, что подобные конструкции возможны и краткость их записи не может не умилять.

Comment: @Construct найн, в первом случае ключом тоже был объект `(n.prototype === Function)`. Т.е. `function(){}` - объект, `(function(){})()` - результат функции. obj[false] выдаст undefined)

@AlexWindHope, ну не знаю... С одной стороны, "может быть когда-нибудь" этому найдется применение, а сейчас это выглядит сложение строки с объектом и деление на массив.

Comment: От идиотизма ни один язык программирования не застрахует. Как по мне - приведенный вами код лишь демонстрирует то, насколько гибок язык, но никак не то, насколько он страшен.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Для начала - немного теории.  Эту ИМХО глупость, в свое время, начал IE, остальными браузерами это не поддерживалось, после - это стало поддерживаться хромом, в настоящее же время - такого рода поведение утвержденно html5 стандартом (да, и там кое-что через Ж, ну да не суть). Соответственно по поводу поддержки - это поддержка действительно на уровне.(за исключением того парадокса, что это не будет работать в старых **не** IE), более того - поддержка останеться и никуда она не денется, соответственно я не совсем понимаю - что правильного в ответе [@Alex Silaev](/users/300/alex-silaev) ?

Ну а теперь перейдем к практической части, такого рода элементы хранятся в глобальной области видимости, соответственно, например, может возникнуть ситуация, типа:

```
<!-- наш HTML -->
<div id="hello">классно работает!11!</div>

<!-- один из наших скриптов -->
var hello = function(){ /* function code... */ }
<!-- другой наш скрипт -->
hello.onclick = function(){ alert(this.innerHTML); }
```

Что в  таком случае произойдет я думаю понятно. Естественно кто-то может возразить, мол - если делать все акуратно, то все будет ок и я не отрицаю, нередко так все и будет. Но, мягко говоря - не всегда. Чем больше кода у вас будет - тем выше будет становиться вероятность поймать неприятный баг. Конечно если вы понимаете что глобальные переменные зло и т.д. и т.п. - вы будете грамотно структуировать свой код, но, в таком случае и элементы выбирать, тоже, будете по человечески. В противном случае - у вас идет жесткая привязка к структуре html, еще жоще чем при document.getElementById('someId'). На самом деле - все это выглядит как магия, соответственно просматривая код, банально, не понятно - откуда взялся, например, этот hello, особенно очевидным это становиться тогда, когда объемы кода становятся, хотя-бы 300+ строк. Допустим мне нужно изменить этот id, я меняю его в DOM'e, ищу по скриптам где он используется, но я так и не нахожу т.к. (уж будьте уверены) - искать я буду именно `$` в случае jq, prototype и getElementById в случае "pure" JS, сейчас я пишу не в контексте себя лично, а в контексте человека который будет смотреть написанный вами код, вашего напарника или того, кто заменяет вас на работе. И, на самом деле - это нормально, знают это далеко не все и, даже в книгах, где об этом упомянаеться - кратко пишут мол, смотрите вот так вот *можно* делать, немного описывают как это работает и потом - *можно*, но не *нужно* и во всех книгах дальше пишется что-то типа - соответственно в нашей книге мы так делать не будем. Конечно я понимаю, что далеко не всегда в книгах все пишут правильно (особенно это справедливо с книгами по javascript'у), но то, что об этом написано далеко не во всех книгах и то, что, например, вы - до сиих пор не знали этого, по моему, уже говорит о том что никому это не нужно. оффтоп - и подтверждает поговорку "меньше знаешь - лучше спишь" =)

Еще хотел бы добавить, к описаному выше, неудобство в плане парной работы с верстальщиком или, что, в данном случае, намного хуже - с другим JS разработчиком.

Вообщем кратко резюмируя - так делать, в абсолютном большинстве случаев, мягко говоря - не рекомендую (не только я), причины (не выдумывая чего-то сложного, а, в реальной жизни, поверьте мне - будут проблемы поинтереснее) описаны выше. Что мы выигрываем? Да, собственно, практически ничего мы и не выигрываем...

Еще одним "типа" аргументом может быть то, что это быстрее - возможно это и так, но getElementById работает настолько быстро (причем абсолютно везде), что руководствоваться этим - не серьезно. Но даже, если вы хотите, то сделайте хотя-бы как-то так:

```
function getElementById(id) {
    return window[id] !== undefined && window[id].id === id
                                 ? window[id] : document.getElementById(id);
}
```

Собственно подобный подход решает проблему "стирания", но, в то-же время, невилизирует краткость записи. С другой стороны - эта функция будет нормально работать везде и в DOM, если элемент сохранился в window - не полезет. Еще раз акцентирую ваше внимание - это экономия на спичках.

Парирую кусок UPD by [[@Антон Мухин](/users/293/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD)](/users/293/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD) по поводу id вида "div-id" - их легко и просто можно достать вызовом window["div-id"], ничего браузер не вычисляет.

Постараюсь подвести очень краткие итоги - просто не используйте это, знайте для того, что-бы можно было понять как работает тот или иной javascript код, не более (ИМХО)

PS: 2 [[@northerner](/users/6536/northerner)](/users/6536/northerner) никто не говорит что они там дураки, они хотят сделать как лучше. По поводу javascript без getElementById - если в вопросе явно спрашивается, "как лучше getElementById или так?", какое отношение к вопросу имеет то, о чем писали вы? Либо я чего-то недопонимаю, либо вы не внимательно читали вопрос.

UPD: Время уже все показало, если бы это было-бы нужно это бы уже давно использовалось бы в широких кругах, т.к. ничего подобного не наблюдается - это никому не нужно (вернее кому-то нужно раз принимают такие стандарты, но вот кому - я без понятия). Еще раз подчерну - речь именно о браузерном javascript'е, возможно, где-то, это удобно и практикуется большинством, тогда конечно - юзайте на здоровье (спасибо кэп).

Comment: А мне нравится такое поведение. Использование id как объекта в Javascript-коде представляется очень естественным обращением к элементам. Я, конечно, пишу на JavaScript не для Web, а для реализации логики QML-интерфейсов, там обращение по id архиудобно и никаких проблем не возникает. Проводя аналогию, подозреваю, удобство доступа по id проявится при реализации интерактива на холсте (canvas) HTML5.

По поводу примера думаю, что его недостаток не в обращении по id, а в обращении к функции глобально. При использовании пространств имен, описанная ситуация невозможна. Есть ли другие примеры проблем

Comment: @northerner - ваши подозрения ничем не подкованы, вообще причем тут html canvas?.. Я очень сильно увлекаюсь этой технологией и, смею вас заверить, код работы с DOM'ом ~= 0, соответственно реально не понял о чем вы.

Приведенные мною примеры верны как для html так и для любой другой древовидной структуры. Собственно огромного, "не убиваемого" недостатка за этим поведением нет, но и ощутимой выгоды - тоже. Соответственно лучше делать так, как это делают все.

Конечно если вы пишите что-то сами от и до - пишите как вам удобно, тут абсолютно фиолетово, я писал в контексте норм масштабов и команды

Comment: А ненравиться мне такое поведение потому, что в JS и так все выстроено вокруг глобальной области, но нет-же, все мало, даешь больше -_-

Comment: И вообще - функционал сомнительный, нужен мягко говоря не каждому и, мягко говоря не всегда, более того - это, без проблем, можно реализовать самому. Соответственно я вообще не понимаю кто утвердил эту (censore).

Comment: Вот этот ответ я и ждал! @AlexWindHope Спасибо!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста

Comment: @AlexWindHope, мои подозрения основаны на двух моментах: 
 1. Существует как минимум одна реализация JavaScript, в которой вообще нет функции getElementById, доступ к свойствам и методам элементов обеспечивается через id - в QML. Но возможностей превратить код в спагетти в QML гораздо меньше, чем в браузерном JavaScript: модификация глобального объекта не допускается, любой код должен быть упакован в пространства имен.
 2. И вот в стандарте HTML5 также разрешают прямое обращение. Протолкнуть что-то в стандарт очень сложно, нужна поддержка нескольких членов комитета, а они там далеко не дураки

Comment: Вопрос я читал. И комментарии тоже читал. Они в основном резко отрицательные. И я не понимаю, почему от этого нововведения в HTML от W3C должно стать всё плохо и использовать его нельзя, если существует QML от Nokia, где всегда так было, все хорошо и не использовать это просто невозможно. Мне на самом деле хотелось вовлечь всех участников обсуждения в дискуссию. Просто очень много отрицательных оценок в комментариях и мало фактов. У Вас в ответе по крайней мере анализ есть.

Ладно, забейте, наверное, лучше всего подождать - время покажет, полезная это фича или ненужная.

Answer (score 12):

[Обсуждение на StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331696/dom-elements-attached-to-the-window-object-via-their-id-expected-behavior) и [еще](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/ie-chrome-are-dom-tree-elements-global-variables-here).

Это поведение IE, которое было потом скопировано другими браузерами, и упомянуто в стандарте HTML5. см. [5.2.4 Named access on the Window object](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/browsers.html#named-access-on-the-window-object).

Суть заключается в том, что в данном случае обращение идет к свойству объекта window. Другими словами, браузеры делают возможным доступ к элементам с указанным id через объект window, который является глобальным контекстом, поэтому window['id'] можно и не писать, достаточно id, ну за исключением невалидных id с точки зрения имени переменной (да, минусы и проч.)...

Такая практика никому особо не нравится и идет речь, чтобы если не убрать данное поведение из стандарта, то сделать доступным хотя бы только для quirks mode, а standard mode не трогать.

[Consider making the global scope pollution by names/ids quirks-only](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=11960)

Comment: @Yura Ivanov хороший ответ, а главное вместительный и понятный! Спасибо.

На стаке увидел от части в вопросе подобно когдато моему [тут][1]


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/74756/простой-вопрос-к-js-скриптерам

Answer (score 8):

Ответ просто в правильности подхода.
Никто не гарантирует, что такой метод "проживет" или будет поддерживаться и дальше. А getElementById будет.

Это примерно тоже самое, что и дорогу на красный свет переходить. Ведь можно, но никто не гарантирует, что после этого с вами ничего не произойдет. (Хотя в России может произойти и на зеленый). Но суть не в этом, а в том, что подходы разные и вероятность несчастного случая тоже.
Тем более, если вдруг не будет поддержки этой штуки, то вам приедтся весь код просматривать и все менять. А если не будет поддержки getElementById, то я просто ее переобъявлю и она у меня появится :)

И собственно ответ на вопрос - скорее отстанете от жизни, если будете его использовать :)

Comment: Суть в том что от стандарного применения я отказываться не собирался... Перебирая методы подхода и прочее, выяснил то что это все работает, вот и стало интересно о существовании подводных камней...

Comment: да к стате, если этот метож работает в IE6 и самом древнем Firefox не говоря уже о опере, вероятность того что этот метод будет отклонен аналогичкна тому же getElementById. Но повтоюсь что оспаривать ничего не берусь!

Comment: Смотрите оф доку;)

Comment: точну ссылку плз)

Comment: у меня кста есть товарищ, нетлешный js'ер, ему еще напишу! ну уперты я) благодаря упертости имею достижения!)

Comment: Занимаюсь js чуть больше 10лет, из них 6 - профессионально. Никогда не использовал такие конструкции и не буду. Хотите писать так - нет проблем, но это плохой код)

Comment: developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference - это в фф. По всем остальным ищите в гугле))

Answer (score 2):

А вы попробуйте дать элементу

```
<div id="div-1">TEXT</div>
```

Как думаете, что будет пытаться сделать браузер при выполнении `div-1`?
Правильно! Он будет пытаться от переменной `div` вычесть 1! Как в таком случае обойтись без выражения

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("div-1");
```

???
**UPD1**
Еще можно добавить! Бывают элементы, создаваемые во время выполнения. Ну им, стало быть, `ID` даются динамически. Было бы глупо для таких случаев не динамически ставить переменные вот так:

```
my_dynamic_id.onclick = function() {
    //Бла-бла-бла
}
```

Лучше, же, наверное, так:

```
// начало какого-нибудь цикла обработки
//....
//получаем ID из какой-нить функции, предоставляющей id элементов
var my_id_i = document.getElementById(getNextDynamicId());
my_id_i.onclick = function() {
    //Бла-бла-бла
}
```

Тут как получается такая ситуация когда можно обращаться непосредственно к элементу `my_div` напрямую? Просто при создании этого `DIV`-элемента, появляется и глобальная переменная `my_div`. Но она перезапишется, объяви вы глобально переменную с таким же именем, как `ID` элемента:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my_div = 'АГА!!!!';
    function aga() {
        alert(my_div);
        alert(document.getElementById(my_div));    
    }
</script>
```

Тут, в первом случае, выведется `"АГА!!!!"`, во втором что-то вроде `"HTMLDivElement"`.
Вот и получается, что ваше приложение может по ошибке или недосмотру сломаться из-за нечаянного объявления переменной с таким же именем, как `ID`, как у вашего элемента.
Так что же вышло? Браузер сначала объявил глобальную переменную my_div, которую мы успешно переписали!
Ну вот как-то так. Даже мой, приведенный тут случай, можно считать "подводным камнем".

Comment: @Антон Мухин Вы так ответили как будто я пропагандирую данный подход... Я собираю информацию на предмет подхода а не рву кишки что я изобрел что-то супер мега необходимое для каждого web мудрильщика!

Из слова мудрильщика - кто желает может убрать букву **р**

Comment: Вот, я привел еще один из подводных камней... :)

Comment: Да и вот, на ваше  
>>Вопрос: Зачем объявлять переменную типа как

var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
и потом к ней обращаться, если обращение можно сделать сразу к mydiv? Поясните!   

прояснил также некоторую ситуацию, "зачем".

Comment: Поддерживаю этот ответ. Я не думаю, что обращение по id непосредственно - грязный хак, недокументированная фича и будет вырезана :) Сам пишу на QML, который тоже скриптуется JavaScript - там использование id элементов как объектов JavaScript является основной рекомендуемой практикой. Но как показано на примерах getElementById() универсален и может использоваться, если напрямую по id не обратиться из-за особенностей синтаксиса или если имя id задано переменной.

Answer (score 0):

Отвечу в ответ на свой вопрос в споре ответов и комментариев отозвавшихся...

Суть: Я всегда использую нативный js в рамках своих проетов, которыми занимаюсь только я.

[[@Alex Silaev](/users/300/alex-silaev)](/users/300/alex-silaev) пожалуй ваш ответ пока лучший но учитывая часть вашего ответа:

> если не будет поддержки
> getElementById, то я просто ее
> переобъявлю и она у меня появится

я напишу некий умный php скрипт котрый преобразует все нужные вхождения в нужных местах и отформатирует js скрипт под все мега новшества дабы не ковыряться в километровом js коде! На данный момент я не вижу причин не использовать тот метод который я привел в примере! Снова ословлюсь в рамках своего проекта!

[[@Антон Мухин](/users/293/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD)](/users/293/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD) открою вам интересную функцию:

```
function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }
```

и далее можите использовать строку из моего примера в вопросе как

```
$("div_1").onclick = function() //...
```

Теперь скажу что в рамках своего проекта я чотко знаю что нужно использовать нижнее подчеркивание а не дефис, это вопервых.

Во вторых я такую мишуру редко использую и в основном в css клсасах! Что относится к программному коду и названиях ID происходит следующим образом var `nodeName` или `id="idName"` давно стараюсь исключать мишуру и лишние знаки!

Comment: Всех знаний не перзнаешь, всех тонкостей не учтешь, всех методов не переметодишь! В некоторых случаях, - одни приемы полезны, в других случаях - другие. Все зависит от конкретной задачи! Тут, @northerner просветил что, оказывается, в некоторых случаях приведенный вами пример, даже рекомендуем!  
Но, глядя на ваше высказывание, что вы пытаетесь исключить мишуру и лишние знаки... Я думаю, что этим не стоит злоупотреблять потому, что, как мне думается, может ухудшить читабельность кода.

Comment: @Антон Мухин - всего, действительно, не узнаешь, но нужно к этому стремиться.

Это **несомненно**, не только может, но и ухудшит читабельность кода