# Наименование переменной и ID тега

Tags: javascript, html, переменные

Допустим у меня в HTML документе есть следующие DOM элементы:

```
<div id=header>...</div>
<div id=menu>...</div>
<div id=legalDocument>...</div>
```

В .js файле, чтобы удобнее было к ним обращаться я задаю переменные для каждого элемента:

```
header = document.getElementById('header');
menu = document.getElementById('menu');
legalDocument = document.getElementById('legalDocument');
```

Что предпочтительнее: Сделать так, чтобы названия переменных полностью совпадали с Id как в примере выше, либо поменять названия переменных, например:

```
headerVar = document.getElementById('header');
menuVar = document.getElementById('menu');
legalDocumentVar = document.getElementById('legalDocument');
```

?

Comment: по поводу `id`: [Зачем использовать getElementById, если можно получить элемент через переменную с именем, равным значению атрибута id?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/91401/186999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вам будет удобнее так и именуйте.

советую почитать эту статью https://learn.javascript.ru/coding-style

p.s. я не вижу смысла дописывать Var, ведь и так очевидно что это переменная :)